# Cache performance of Quick Sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, caching, quicksort

I recently came across this doubt.

We choose Quick sort over Merge Sort because cache performance of quick sort is better than merge sort.
Can somebody explain how?

Comment: http://cr.yp.to/bib/1999/lamarca-sorting.pdf

Comment: One factor will be that typical mergesort implementations are not in-place, so they require around twice the memory of typical quicksort implementations.  ("Typical mergesort" = not the highly complicated and slow in-place versions; "typical quicksort" = quicksort with heuristic pivot selection on "nice" inputs that give O(nlog n) time and space behaviour.  Technically quicksort is not in-place either, since it needs at least O(log n) extra space for the recursion stack, and O(n) unless expensive median selection is used for pivoting.)

Answer (score 2):

The Average Case does not exist!

As best and worst case often are extremes rarely occurring in practice, average case analysis is done. But any average case analysis assume some distribution of inputs! For sorting, the typical choice is the random permutation model (tacitly assumed on Wikipedia).

Why O-Notation?

Discarding constants in analysis of algorithms is done for one main reason: If I am interested in exact running times, I need (relative) costs of all involved basic operations (even still ignoring caching issues, pipelining in modern processors ...). Mathematical analysis can count how often each instruction is executed, but running times of single instructions depend on processor details, e.g. whether a 32-bit integer multiplication takes as much time as addition.

There are two ways out:

Fix some machine model.

This is done in Don Knuth's book series “The Art of Computer Programming” for an artificial “typical” computer invented by the author. In volume 3 you find exact average case results for many sorting algorithms, e.g.

Quicksort: 11.667(n+1)ln(n)−1.74n−18.74
Mergesort: 12.5nln(n)
Heapsort: 16nln(n)+0.01n
Insertionsort: 2.25n2+7.75n−3ln(n) Runtimes of several sorting algorithms

These results indicate that Quicksort is fastest. But, it is only proved on Knuth's artificial machine, it does not necessarily imply anything for say your x86 PC. Note also that the algorithms relate differently for small inputs:
Runtimes of several sorting algorithms for small inputs

Analyse abstract basic operations.

For comparison based sorting, this typically is swaps and key comparisons. In Robert Sedgewick's books, e.g. “Algorithms”, this approach is pursued. You find there

Quicksort: 2nln(n) comparisons and 13nln(n) swaps on average
Mergesort: 1.44nln(n) comparisons, but up to 8.66nln(n) array accesses (mergesort is not swap based, so we cannot count that).
Insertionsort: 14n2 comparisons and 14n2 swaps on average.
As you see, this does not readily allow comparisons of algorithms as the exact runtime analysis, but results are independent from machine details.